# Logging same class to different file, if war is different

Tags: java, tomcat, logging, log4j, slf4j

I need to split 1 batch application to 3 different. Code is almost the same, I have just modified ANT build script, and excluded or included some dependencies for different app. Than I have set different web.xml for each war. Each web.xml defines different spring application context with different beans for different behaviour.

All wars run on one tomcat server. Application used log4j, but now I refactored it to use slf4j instead. Thought I still need to use log4j under slf4j.

The problem I have is that each application log must appear in different log file,
even though class names are the same.

- I can't write different log4j.properties file, because administrators placed it in tomcat/lib folder for all applications.
- I have tried to place 3 files in tomcat/lib and change configuration file name for each application when initializing servlet, but it changed for all applications at same time.

Only solution I can think of now is to wrap log4j-over-slf4j, create 3 different slf4j log factories, that would append some prefix for each log name. For example, if I have this log:

```
 private final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MainProcessor.class);
```

Each logging factory would genarate these logging names (with prefixes app1,app2 and app3) :

```
app1.com.test.MainProcessor
app2.com.test.MainProcessor
app3.com.test.MainProcessor
```

Is there any better way to deal with this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

Try using a hook method, fire event, etc. so the logging doesn't happen in the class that is shared across the applications, but in some (top) class that is unique per application.
Variation is to statically access some logging class, use a singleton, etc. from the class where the logging should occur, but set context to that logging class on app initialization.

Comment: I thought about similar solution, but there are about 10 logs for each application, and amount can change according to configuration, so I can't use one unique class.

Second solution is another alternative, but I can't decide if it is better than my solution with factories. This would not require building additional jars, but I would have to modify all classes, make getting logger more difficult and have to manage additional singleton class.

Comment: You could use a single class per application or a singleton, because you would get a logger using both the caller and the knowledge of what the app was. Another thing - have you considered setting configuration programatically? This can be done using both a file or Properties instance.